# Angular 1.x image upload preview code not updating DOM

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.x I want to provide a drag and drop box for uploading images. When the images have been dropped I want to show a preview in the front end.

This is my code:

```
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {

        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.dropText = 'Drop files here...';
            $scope.dropClass = '';
        });

        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

        if (files.length > 0) {

                $scope.listing.listing_images = [];
                $scope.imagepreview = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    // push the image to be uploaded 
                    $scope.listing.listing_images.push(files[i]);

                    // push the image to be rendered
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $scope.imagepreview[i] = e.target.result;              
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                }

                console.log($scope.imagepreview);
                console.log($scope.imagepreview.length);

        }
    }, false);
```

If I drop say 3 images into the dropbox area and I console.log $scope.imagepreview I can see that the image is stored - so far so good!

```
[]
0: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4fzyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg"
1: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4f8ERXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg"
2: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4f+eRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Then on the very next line:

```
$scope.imagepreview.length 0
```

This makes no sense and looks like a bug to me, how can Scope object have data but also have a length of 0?

The problem is that in my template when I try to ng-repeat on the $scope.previewimages the object is empty so no images are rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: The prototype for the array is an empty array. The prototype array has the constructor and other array methods. That is normal and not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing an $apply block for the reader load event:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // push the image to be uploaded 
    $scope.listing.listing_images.push(files[i]);

    // push the image to be rendered
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        //IMPORTANT
        $scope.$apply(function() { 
            $scope.imagepreview[i] = e.target.result;
        });              
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
}
```

When the FileReader `load` event handler modifies $scope, the AngularJS frame needs to digest the changes and update the DOM.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)